# create multipath for local partition

Tags: rhel, partition

Is it possible to create multipath to local partition?
I got partition /dev/sda3 and I need /dev/mapper/mpath01 to be pointing to it.

This is what I added in my kickstart (rhel 5.7)

```
part /my_mount_point --size=2500 --ondisk=sda --fstype ext3
multipath --name=mpath01 --device=/dev/sda3 --rule=failover
```

Partition is created ok but I don't have /dev/mapper/mpath01 file

multipath -l also shows nothing (service is running)

Answer (score 0):

Multipath for local partitions wont help you much. Its purpose is to create logical paths to network partitions/disks like SAN LUNs to be fault tolerant. Which means you can loose one path to your disk but the second one will still be active.

With that said you can still see a partition with multipath if you rely want to. You just need to un **blacklist** local partitions in the configuration file which is **/etc/multipath.conf**

Here is a basic multipath.conf file:

```
defaults {
   user_friendly_names yes
   path_group_policy failover
}

blacklist {
   devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
   devnode "^(hd|xvd|vd)[a-z]*"
   wwid "*"
}

# Make sure our multipath devices are enabled.

blacklist_exceptions {
   wwid "20017380006c00034"
   wwid "20017380006c00035"
   wwid "20017380006c00036"
   wwid "20017380006c00037"
}

multipaths {
  multipath {
      wwid "20017380006c00034"
      alias mpath0
  }
  multipath {
      wwid "20017380006c00035"
      alias mpath1
  }
  multipath {
      wwid "20017380006c00036"
      alias mpath2
  }
  multipath {
      wwid "20017380006c00037"
      alias mpath3
  }
}
```

http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/redhat/rh_multipathing.htm
You can specify your partition in there and they will show up with **mltipath -ll** command.